# SSH Authentication stopped working

Tags: ssh, git

Following the macOS update (to Monterey 12.6.1) my ssh authentication stopped working. I was getting a "Repository not found. Please make sure you have the correct access rights."

I have reset my ssh setup and followed Github's official guidelines on [link](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent)

My current `~/.ssh/config` looks like this:

```
Host *.github.com
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

I now get a new error that I haven't been able to solve. When I run `ssh -T git@hostname`, I get "Bad configuration option: usekeychain"

---

I have tried the following fixes:

- Adding to config: `IgnoreUnknown UseKeychain`
- Adding to config: `IgnoreUnknown AddKeysToAgent,UseKeychain` ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47455300/ssh-config-bad-configuration-option-usekeychain-on-mac-os-sierra-10-12-6))
- Clearing DNS cache: `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder`
- Removed  `~/.ssh/known_hosts`
- Changed hostname to `Host *`

Comment: Were you using some replacement OpenSSH?

Comment: No, using OpenSSH_9.1p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1s

Comment: I wondered because it got `UseKeychain` from somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue to this when I had accidentally written over my public and private key. To overcome and reset this I

1. Deleted all github related ssh keys from the key chain and .ssh/ directory.
2. Deleted github ssh key from github ui.
3. Ran ssh-add -D to remove all identities from the agent.
4. Re-created the ssh key and saved the public key on github.

Obviously this is quite heavy handed!

Comment: Thanks, Simon, this is perfect! Solution number 3 solved my issue. I think that one of the identities from the agent was cached and that is what was causing the whole issue. `ssh-add -D` solved this issue!

Comment: exactly the same happned to me with 12.6.2 update (maybe earlier. only experienced it today)
`ssh-add -D` solved all annoying git issues. Thanks!